# Как подтянуть изменения из Git remote в fork

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Форкнул проект на гитхабе, работал локально в "селф-бранчах", пушил, мерджил, отправлял PR(их принимали) на **parent-repo**. Но теперь хочу **подтянуть из Parent  >> Fork** не могу решить эту задачу, куда копать?

Comment: команда называется [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/FooBar
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Comment: Выполнил вышеуказанное. Ожидаемого результата нет. Варианты?

Comment: Проверить все еще раз